# How to covert XBRL to CSV using python

Tags: xml, csv, xbrl

I'm currently working with XBRL format and was wondering how to convert it into CSV, I used XBRLParser() and then hit the dead end from there. This is the  [datasample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGC77.png). I would really appreciate if someone can help me or recommend me resources to resolve this problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use XSLT transformation to convert XML file into *.csv format

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)